# Using jenkins only as a backend with some better UI as a frontend

Tags: user-interface, jenkins

I am interested to know if someone has explored using Jenkins only as a backend tool but use some better web based UI to start build, and report job details.

Jenkins is really amazing at what it does and with pipeline, it actually does lot of things that a modern build system might need. However, I am really not happy with the UI it gives users, it is just very dull and is not very intuitive. I was hoping if someone had explored developing their own UI to show the different jobs configured in jenkins, taking inputs from users and running the jobs and showing the logs in a more intuitive way.

Comment: You should explore REST API of jenkins then you can build any front end on top of it.

Comment: Was looking for something that already existed, for now seems like Blue Ocean Plugin is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

For now, I found that [Blue Ocean Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/blueocean/) is the best way to get a much improved UI for jenkins.